# How can I process a Spark DataFrame in groups by a column's values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a DataFrame that I need to write into our custom data store. This data store requires that the data is written in groups depending on a specific column's (account_id) values.
E.g. given this data:

```
account_id | date       | value
         1 | 2023-01-01 | 1
         1 | 2023-01-02 | 2
         2 | 2023-01-01 | 3
```

I need to process the group having account_id 1 separately from the group having account_id 2.

I tried this (in Scala) using
`df.repartition(df.col("account_id")).foreachPartition(processPartition)`

I expected my mock data store in my unit test to receive 2 calls, one with the 2 rows with account_id 1 and another with the one row with account id 2 but instead it only received a single write call containing all 3 rows. It's as if Spark was ignoring my partitioning requirement.

Reading up on this, I get the impression that partitioning is purely a performance tool (for controlling how parallelism is used) and that Spark here decides that there is no reason for even splitting the tiny frame. However, I cannot find any documentation that would spell this out clearly. My problem is that in my case it's not about performance but about correctness. Neither can I find any documentation telling me what to do instead. I came across DataFrameWriter's partitionBy, but this one's docs all talk about files on disk while I need to write to our custom data store using the client library I have already written.

Lastly, I have found sort of similar questions on StackOverflow, but they explicitly mentioned that the DataFrame is small and performance not an issue, so the accepted answer was to get the list of distinct values first and then iterating over that and creating new DataFrames filtering for these values ala `account_ids.map(id => (df.where(($"account_id" === id))))` but this would defeat Spark's implicit parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning guarantees that all accounts with the same `account_id` end up in the same partition, but there is no guarantee that a single partition only contains a single `account_id`. Usually you will have more `account_id`s than partitions, so Spark has no chance to create a single partition per `account_id`.
If you omit the number of partitions when calling `repartition` Spark will use the default (`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`) for the number of partitions.

However you can sort the rows within each partition by your key (no additional shuffling required) and then process each key seperately:

```scala
//create testdata with 8 keys distributed over 5 partitions
val df = spark.createDataset(for( x <- 1 to 100 ) yield (x%8, x))
  .toDF("key", "value")
  .repartition(5, 'key)

//the method handling the data store
def doSomething(in:List[Row]): Unit = {
  if( in.length > 0 ) {
    println(in) //replace this line with whatever code should work only on a single account_id
  }
}

//processing the partitions in parallel
df.sortWithinPartitions("key")
  .foreachPartition{it:Iterator[Row] => {
    var curKey:Option[Int] = Option.empty
    var curList: ListBuffer[Row] = ListBuffer()
    while(it.hasNext) {
      val row = it.next()
      val k = row.getAs[Int]("key")
      if( curKey == Some(k) ) {
        curList += row
      }
      else {
        doSomething(curList.toList)
        curList = ListBuffer()
        curList += row
        curKey = Some(k)
      }
    }
    doSomething(curList.toList)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
List([1,1], [1,9], [1,17], [1,25], [1,33], [1,41], [1,49], [1,57], [1,65], [1,73], [1,81], [1,89], [1,97])
List([2,2], [2,10], [2,18], [2,26], [2,34], [2,42], [2,50], [2,58], [2,66], [2,74], [2,82], [2,90], [2,98])
List([6,6], [6,14], [6,22], [6,30], [6,38], [6,46], [6,54], [6,62], [6,70], [6,78], [6,86], [6,94])
List([0,8], [0,16], [0,24], [0,32], [0,40], [0,48], [0,56], [0,64], [0,72], [0,80], [0,88], [0,96])
List([3,3], [3,11], [3,19], [3,27], [3,35], [3,43], [3,51], [3,59], [3,67], [3,75], [3,83], [3,91], [3,99])
List([5,5], [5,13], [5,21], [5,29], [5,37], [5,45], [5,53], [5,61], [5,69], [5,77], [5,85], [5,93])
List([4,4], [4,12], [4,20], [4,28], [4,36], [4,44], [4,52], [4,60], [4,68], [4,76], [4,84], [4,92], [4,100])
List([7,7], [7,15], [7,23], [7,31], [7,39], [7,47], [7,55], [7,63], [7,71], [7,79], [7,87], [7,95])
```

Each row in the output is created by a single call to `doSomething` and contains only rows with a unique key while still processing the partitions in parallel.

Comment: Thank you so much! This mirrors what I eventually came up with yesterday. The key difference is that I haven't added sortWithinPartition in my code yet. It seems to work anyway, and I think it's because Spark has to first partition the data to then distribute the partitions over the workers, thus the iterator will see one partition after another and not intermingled. BUT like so many important details, this is not documented, so I cannot rely on this behavior and I will add the sorting as you suggested. It's really helpful to get this kind of clarity!